# Using variables as cache for queries results in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, global-variables

I'm wondering if it's a good idea (performance wise) to store queries results in variables and update them only every few minute, since I have multiple database queries(MongoDB) in my node application that don't need to be up to date and some of them are a bit complex.

I'm thinking about something like this :

```
var queryResults = [];
myModel.find().exec(function(err, results) {
    queryResults = results;
});
```

Then :

```
var interval = 10 * 60 * 1000;
setInterval(function() {
    myModel.find().exec(function(err, results) {
        queryResults = results;
    });
}, interval);
```

And when I need to send the query results to my views engine :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {entries : queryResults});
});
```

Is this a good way to cache and display the same queries results to multiple clients?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module instead of creating your cache layer:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache

You have to be careful not to put huge amount of data into memory. If you want to push in there millions of results, probably it is not a good idea.

Comment: Do you know how this package is better than using variables directly?

Comment: This module will store the values in memory as well so there is no difference from this point of view. It is pretty easy to understand what it is doing if you check the source code. Using this you will avoid creating you cache layer.